# How can I use a dictionary to add and subtract numbers when required to do so?

Tags: python, list

So I'm trying to write a code that will return the total of points each person has. Everyone starts with 0 and the input will assign `'++'` or `'--'` behind each person directly just like `"Jim++", "John--"` which means that Jim gains one point while John loses one point.

**Every `'++'` equals to one point added**

**Every `'--'` equals to one point deducted.**

So if my input looks like this

`["Jim++", "John--", "Jeff++", "Jim++", "John--", "Jeff--", "June++"]`

this is what my output should look like

["Jim": "2", "John":"-2", "Jeff":"0", "June":"1"]

I'm trying to keep it simple without using stuff like key = lamda, import, or collections.iter since I'm new to this and I would prefer to keep things simply for now.

Here is what I have, which apparently doesn't work at all..

```
def keepTabs(actions: list[str]):
    d = {'++' : +1, '--': -1}
    return d[actions]

print(keepTabs(actions=["Jim++", "John--", "Jeff++", "Jim++", "John--", "Jeff--", "June++"]))
```

What changes to my code should I make to make sure this works??

**I was informed about the usage of dictionaries, so I was just wondering if that could be used to solve this problem**

Answer (score 1):

Hello from your questions example i assume that you start with a dictionary like:

```
currentTabs = {"Jim":1, "John": -1 , "Jeff":-1, "June" : 0}
```

a dictionary with ALL the keys/names you want initialised with a value

you could then have an input function which will return you a new dictionary

```
def KeepTabs(currentTabs, actions):
    for combined in actions:
        key = combined[:-2] # get the name IE [Jeff]--
        action = combined[-2:] # get the action ie Jeff[--]
        # decide what the action means
        if action == "++":
            value = 1
        elif action == "--":
            value = -1
        else:
            value = 0
        # modify the key in the dictionary by the value
        currentTabs[key] =  currentTabs[key] + value
    return currentTabs
```

this function breaks the input action into its key and value pair, which is what we use to find the current value in the dictionary.

you could replace the if/else statements with a dictionary similar to how you have done.

```
def KeepTabs(currentTabs, actions):
    for combined in actions:
        key = combined[:-2] # get the name IE [Jeff]--
        action = combined[-2:] # get the action ie Jeff[--]
        # decide what the action means
        d = {'++' : +1, '--': -1}
        # modify the key in the dictionary by the value
        currentTabs[key] =  currentTabs[key] + dict[action]
    return currentTabs
```

but this will crash if you pass an invalid key like "-+", this could be solved in other ways like a default dict.

Comment: Thank you for ur response, but btw everyone starts with a 0 btw, Like this is my input: input_list = ["Jim++", "John--", "Jeff++", "Jim++", "John--", "Jeff--", "June++"]                      and this is my intended output, {'Jim': 2, 'John': -2, 'Jeff': 0, 'June': 1}

Comment: i didn't spot there were multiples of the same name, but this implementation still works. It is a demonstration of how you can have multiple rounds of "KeepTabs" and have a total tally

Answer (score 0):

Solution to add to the points to the dict entry by checking the string

```
input_list = ["Jim++", "John--", "Jeff++", "Jim++", "John--", "Jeff--", "June++"]
```

You just want the dict to keep a count of points they have and a function to get the name from the list entry.

```
def get_name(string): # format to get the name by removing the + and - characters
    return string.replace("+", "").replace("-", "")

output = {}
for entry in input_list:
    name = get_name(entry)
    if name not in output:
        output[name] = 0  # add the initial entry and start at 0
    if "++" in entry:
        output[name] += 1  # add points
    if "--" in entry:
        output[name] -= 1  # subtract points

print(output)
>> {'Jim': 2, 'John': -2, 'Jeff': 0, 'June': 1}
```

Comment: hello, thank u for ur response, I was just wondering what is input_list in your code??

Comment: @DaveShah It's your list you provided in the post, also the 2nd line of my answer

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want:

```
def get_name_from_action(name: str):
    d = {'++': 1, '--': -1}
    name_action = [name, 0]
    for key, value in d.items():
        if name.__contains__(key):
            name_action[0] = name.replace(key, '')
            name_action[1] = value
    return {'name': name_action[0], 'action': name_action[1]}


def keep_tabs(names_actions_list):
    names_dic = {}
    for name_action in names_actions_list:
        name_increment = get_name_from_action(name_action)
        name = name_increment['name']
        action = name_increment['action']
        if name not in names_dic:
            names_dic[name] = 0
        names_dic[name] = names_dic[name] + action

    return names_dic


print(keep_tabs(names_actions_list=['Jim++', 'John--', 'Jeff++', 'Jim++', 'John--', 'Jeff--', 'June++']))
```

Answer (score -1):

This solution should be fairly extensible.

```
from collections import defaultdict
data = ["Jim++", "John--", "Jeff++", "Jim++", "John--", "Jeff--", "June++"]
operators = {'++': lambda x: x + 1, '--': lambda x: x - 1}
result = defaultdict(int)

for name_op in data:
    name, op = name_op[:-2], name_op[-2:]
    result[name] = operators[op](result[name])
```